# Laravel API : Call to a member function validate() on array

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel as an API with Passport Password Grant Token. I need to validate user attributes from the request but I'm getting an error with `validate()` method.

My `update` method below...

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = [
        'last_name' => ['string'],
        'first_name' => ['string']
    ];
    $validator = $request->user->validate($attributes);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

...is returning this error log:

> local.ERROR: Call to a member function validate() on array {"userId":1234,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function validate() on array at /Users/me/my-project/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:122)

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: This line throw the error ` return $validator;`?

Comment: @Droid `$request->user->validate($attributes)` returns the error

Answer (score 0):

to get the current user from request I think you should use [user()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Authenticatable.html) method not user property ...

anyway .. to get validator from an array with rules, you can use [Validator::make](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) method:

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),  $attributes);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator; // here I think you should redirect to error page
    }
```